# ¿Cómo buscar por Objeto de Referencia en una ruta GET usando Express y Moongose?

Tags: mongodb, express

Tengo una simple base de datos "diseñada" con 3 Schemas en Moongose: `examen.js`,`pregunta.js`, y `respuesta.js`

**examen.js:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ExamenSchema = new Schema({
    titulo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir un titulo']
    },
    numero_preguntas: {
        type: Number
    },
    acabado: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})

const Examen = mongoose.model('examen', ExamenSchema)

module.exports = Examen;
```

**pregunta.js**:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PreguntaSchema = new Schema({
    examen: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'examens'
    },
    pregunta: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir una pregunta']
    }
});

const Pregunta = mongoose.model('pregunta', PreguntaSchema)

module.exports = Pregunta;
```

Pregunta tiene el campo `examen` que es donde se tiene que meter el ObjectId de un `examen`, para que se sepa a que examen pertenece esa pregunta. Obviamente se pueden agregar varias preguntas con el mismo ObjectId en el campo `examen` ya que los examenes tiene varias preguntas habitualmente.

Lo que quiero es tener una ruta GET para obtener las preguntas que pertenecen a un ObjectId (es decir, obtener las preguntas de un examen en concreto).

Actualmente sólo tengo la ruta Get para obtener una pregunta por id:

```js
router.get('/pregunta/:preguntaId', (req,res) => {

    const id = req.params.preguntaId;
    Pregunta.findById(id)
            .exec()
            .then(doc => {
                console.log(doc)
                res.status(200).json(doc)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                res.status(500).json({error: err})
            })
})
```

Me pregunto si existe algún método como el de arriba `findById` que funcione para lo que yo busco:

```js
router.get('/pregunta/:referenciaExamen', (req,res) => {

    const id_ExamenDeProgramar = req.params.referenciaExamen;
    // Pregunta.Buscar preguntas asignadas con el ObjectId(id_ExamenDeProgramar)
    //
            
})
```

Hacer lo siguiente no ha servido:

```
const id = req.params.referenciaExamen;
Pregunta.find({examen: id})
```

Answer (score 1):

A mi punto de vista te estas metiendo en un problema de `aggregate`. Para lograr lo que quieres hacer vas a necesitar algo como esto:

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.schema.ObjectId

var arregloAggregate = [
    {
        $match: {
            examen: ObjectId(id)
        }
    },

    {
        $group: {
            _id: $examen
            // ... mas codigo
        }

    }

    // Mas codigo ....


]


PreguntaSchema.aggregate(arregloAggregate).exec()....
```

Yo lo resolveria con un schema de esta forma:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ExamenSchema = new Schema({
    titulo: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'debes escribir un titulo']
    },

    preguntas: [

        pregunta: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'debes escribir una pregunta']
        },

        respuesta: String
    ]
})



const Examen = mongoose.model('examen', ExamenSchema)

module.exports = Examen;
```

Después si hay un alumno que deba hacerlo solo referenciamos sus respuestas correctas

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ExamenSchema = require('./examen.model')

const AplicanteSchema = new Schema({
    examenes: [{
        examen: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'examens'
        },
        aciertos: Number,
        malas: Number,
        calificacion: Number,

    }]
})



const Aplicante = mongoose.model('examen', AplicanteSchema)

module.exports = Aplicante;
```

Comment: al declarar el array dentro de ExamenSchema me da error de sintaxis en los objetos dentro de preguntas, diciendo 'expected ,' ¿Por que será? También intente simplemente importando el schema Completo y metiendolo en el array y me da un type error de ' Invalid schema configuration: `model` is not a valid type within the array ' Será porque tengo algo mal en mongoose, verdad?

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y poner el error que te da?

Comment: Si gracias, de hecho mejor voy a abrir un hilo porque sino va a cambiar mucho la pregunta.